# Here api won't draw on map using Geojson, can't read property geojson of undefined

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I am trying to draw various polygons on a map using geojson files. How do I go about doing this?

I am using version 3 and have copied the example code but it isn't working. I have tried linking more of the javascript source files and even tried making the shape manually with the polygon function but that didn't work either.

```js
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    app_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    app_code: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    useCIT: true,
    useHTTPS: true
})
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers()

// Initialize a map - this map is centered over Europe
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    defaultLayers.normal.map, {
        center: {
            lat: 102
                                lng: 50
        },
        zoom: 9,
        pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
    })
console.log(map)
this.map = map
// Add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize())

var reader = new H.data.geojson.Reader('./path/to/file.json');
reader.parse();
this.map.addLayer(reader.getLayer());
        }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-data.js"></script>
```

I expect the polygon to be drawn on the map like it does on a site like geojson.com, but all I get is this error in the console: ('cannot read property 'geojson' of undefined'). The map and everything else works fine.

I suspect it's something to do with H.data being undefined. But I'm not sure why that would be. Any ideas?

I apologise if this is hard to read, I haven't done one before. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use HERE Map API Version 3.1, please see below quick start tutorial.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/quick-start.html

You need to use APIKEY instead of APP_CODE and APP_ID.

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  'apikey': 'API-KEY'
});
```

Change base layer object to below.

```
 defaultLayers.normal.map -> defaultLayers.vector.normal.map
```

You need to put ',' and might to switch lng and lat in center property.

```
  center: {
      lng: 102,
      lat: 50
   },
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Yeah thank you, this helped point me to the problem that there was an older version of the here api referenced in the application and they were conflicting. Updated it and it works as expected now, just had to makes sure the version was the same across the whole application.